# jQuery for XUL?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, xul

I have read on the internet and found out that jQuery works OK on XUL.

My questions are:

- Are there any jQuery plugins that are specially made to work with XUL?
- Is there any other jQuery-like library that was specially made for XUL?

I have not yet tested jQuery on XUL, I'm just asking these questions for curiosity.

Answer (score 5):

Relevant SO question: [Is it possible to use jQuery to manipulate XUL elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693174/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-to-manipulate-xul-elements)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
    <!DOCTYPE window>
    <window
        xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
        xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <html:script type="application/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"/>
        <html:script type="application/javascript" src="myjs.js"/>
```

`myjs.js`

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
$(window).load(function() {
    console.log($(document));
});
```

Comment: please, can you detail your answer ? just code, is not a full one.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late to answer, but I want to post this so anyone else having the same question can try this:

Check this out, many of the functions in jQuery 1.9.1 worked for me: http://digitalmihailo.blogspot.com/2008/05/jquery-and-dynamic-html-in-xul.html

It's basically defining the default namespace as XHTML instead of XUL, as the author says.

However, the `.append('<p>something</p>')` example didn't work for me, but I tried with `.html('<p>something</p>')` and it did.

Hope it helps.