# Is jQuery 1.8.2 incompatible with a Firefox 16 extension?

Tags: firefox, jquery, firefox-addon

Here is some sample xul and a little bit of script I added for this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://linktargetfinder/skin/skin.css" type="text/css"?> 
<!DOCTYPE linktargetfinder SYSTEM "chrome://linktargetfinder/locale/translations.dtd">
<overlay id="sample" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <html:script type="application/x-javascript" src="jquery.js" />
 <script>
   $(window).load(function(){
     $('#loginBtn).click(function(){
      alert("hi!");
    });
   });
 </script>
```

jquery.js is the uncompressed version of jQuery 1.8.2. In my script, I get $ or jQuery is undefined each and every time, and I am including my script file AFTER loading up jquery. If I go down to 1.7.2 I don't get the error anymore. If there is a better way to load jQuery and make AJAX calls from a Firefox extension I would love to hear it.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950976/jquery-for-xul