# prototype plugin for cross-domain-request? (to other host's websites!)

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Are there any plugins or best-practices for ajax cross-domain-querys?

I found only this one: http://www.mellowmorning.com/2007/10/25/introducing-a-cross-site-ajax-plugin-for-prototype/ but it didn't work for me...

**edit:** I tried it first with prototype 1.7, after switch to 1.5 it worked... But why isn't it supported anymore in 1.7?! Any idea's how to get work in 1.7?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't find a native Prototype solution then you can try using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) just for [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) and Prototype for everything else. It's only 29kB and you can hot-link from Google (or [other CDNs](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery) to choose). Just include both Prototype and jQuery in your HTML and remember to call jQuery.noConflict() because otherwise jQuery would use the $() function which Prototype also uses:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

And now you can use both of them in your script with something like this:

```
// using jQuery:
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://...',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        // ...
    },
    success: yourHandler
});

// using Prototype:
function yourHandler(data) {
    // use returned data
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/_rsp/SFkuN/) (works with Prototype 1.7 and jQuery 1.5)

Comment: No i don't really want to use jquery... or better say: i can't do this in the project.

Comment: Could you say *why*? I am actually interested to know because there was a question yesterday on [what are the usual reasons not to use jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099949/what-are-some-empirical-technical-reasons-not-to-use-jquery) and in [my reply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099949/what-are-some-empirical-technical-reasons-not-to-use-jquery/5100169#5100169) I enumerated three reason that I've heard: file size, speed and concerns about intellectual property, all of which don't seem particularly reasonable considering the alternatives. Could you say what is your reason?

Comment: Also, would you use it if it was `SomePrototypePlugin.ajax({ ... });` instead of `jQuery.ajax({ ... });`? Because it does cross-domain AJAX queries, the license is the same as in Prototype (MIT), works great with Prototype 1.7 ([TESTED](http://jsfiddle.net/_rsp/SFkuN/)), it's fast, clean, robust, portable... Maybe you could tell whoever is stopping you from using jQuery that it's a Prototype plugin? ;) Just an idea...

Comment: @eav I would also like to hear any reasons against jQuery.