# Type error: x is undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I have this markup

```
<form name="sortbyformtop">
   <select onchange="location.href=sortbyformtop.sortbyselecttop.options[selectedIndex].value" id="sortbyselecttop">
      <option value="/Search"></option>
      <option value="/Search?sortby=accommodationtype">Accommodation type</option>
      ...
   </select>
</form>
```

Whenever I select one of the options in the drop down list I get this Javascript error in Firebug:

```
TypeError: sortbyformtop.sortbyselecttop is undefined
```

Is this sort of thing possible in some way?

Comment: What is the value of `sortbyformtop`?

Comment: We probably need more code, here it is really undefined...

Comment: This is the sort of thing where you would make your life much easier if you used some library like jQuery to handle all of the DOM mess for you (unless you are really experienced with all of its quirks and annoyances). If you are worried about any downside of using a library then read [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099949/what-are-some-empirical-technical-reasons-not-to-use-jquery/5100169#5100169).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shorter version:

```
location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
```

Answer (score 4):

try with

```
location.href= document.getElementById('sortbyselecttop').options[document.getElementById('sortbyselecttop').selectedIndex].value;
```

or shortly

```
location.href= this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
```

since `this` in that context is equivalent to `document.getElementById('sortbyselecttop');`

---

`selectedIndex` needs to be tied to a specific select element (it's a property of the select itself), otherwise you are looking for a global (undefined) variable called `selectedIndex`

Comment: I get TypeError: document.getElementById("sortbyselecttop")

Comment: how many elements with that id you have in the page? if you have only one `sortbyselecttop` the code should work fine. Or try my update

Comment: well, if you use the `this` version you could evaluate to completely remove those id

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `sortbyformtop.sortbyselecttop` give `this` or `document.getElementById('sortbyselecttop')`.

```
document.getElementById('sortbyselecttop').options[document.getElementById('sortbyselecttop').selectedIndex].value
```

Or

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to do this in an inline event handler?

I'm sure it is possible to do what you are trying to do - I think you might need a 'name' attribute on your select element though rather than an ID, but it may be easier to have a seperate function give you a bit more flexibility - and then call the function from your event handler instead.

```
onchange="doSomething();"
```