# Adding a class to a child of a button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to work out how to add a class to a child element of a button, specifically to the `<i>` below:

```
<button><i class="icon-undo"></i> Undo</button>
```

Ideally, using plain JavaScript, there'd be a function which can be added to the button (i.e. `<button onclick="function()">`) which would add the class "icon-spin" to the child `<i>` of whatever element was clicked (so it could be used in multiple places in the same page).

Comment: "Button tag: not worth the trouble, just use input for now." [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903453/what-disadvantages-are-there-to-the-button-tag-it-seems-there-are-quite-a-fe)

Comment: Why even have an <i> in the element? Can't you just add a class to the button and with a some padding get the same result?

Comment: It has to be <button> and <i> because I'm using Font Awesome

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe the code in this question helps....  posted the answer today itself. Just pass 'this' to the function and you could do wonders to the DOM thereafter

[get nearby sibling in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477791/get-nearby-sibling-in-javascript)

Comment: in the case where the answer to an older question is also an answer to a new question, the new question should be closed as duplicate, not have the answer copy and pasted from the older question.