# Is it possible to write jQuery inside XUL file?

Tags: jquery, firefox, xul

I want to use jQuery for my XUL files. Generally I use XUL Explorer to create and text each page individually & it's really to use script blocks inside the XUL files like this:

We can write scripts inside script blocks in XUL file itself.

```
 <script type="application/x-javascript">
    <![CDATA[
        // your code here
    ]]>
    </script>
```

or

```
<script>
</script>
```

To use jQuery we have to link the files like this:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://axead/content/jquery.js" />
 <script type="application/javascript" src="chrome://myapp/content/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"/>
```

I use XUL Explorer a lot to create & test XUL files using JavaScript but when I started using XUL files with jQuery in XUL Explorer isn't working. I referred this thread/post:
[Is it possible to use jQuery to manipulate XUL elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693174/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-to-manipulate-xul-elements)

Is there any way to use/write jQuery inside XUL file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use jQuery to manipulate XUL elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693174/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-to-manipulate-xul-elements)